# how to summarize yearly average temperature from all given daily observation time series with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am wondering `dplyr` provide any useful utilities to conduct quick data aggregation on land surface temperature time series. However, I already extracted gridded data of Germany from `E-OBS` dataset ([`E-OBS` grid data](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/downloadchunks.php)) and rendered this extracted raster grid in tabular data with `excel` format. Now, in newly exported data, data has shown with a respective geo-coordinate pair with 15 years temperature observation (1012 rows ,15x365/366 columns). Plase take a look the data on the fly: [time series data](http://jmp.sh/v/dXIe4QmEGdqrmmAY4eoO).

Here is what I want to do, the data on the fly [time series data](http://jmp.sh/v/dXIe4QmEGdqrmmAY4eoO), I want to do data aggregation by year because original observation was done by daily level observation. In particular, each geo-coordinate pair, I intend to calculate an average yearly temperature for each year and all operation goes to 15 years. More specifically, after the aggregation done, I want to put the result in new data.frame where original geo-coordinate pair come along, but add new column such as `1980_avg_temp`, `1981_avg_temp,`1982_avg_temp` and so on. So I want to reduce data dimension by column, introducing new aggregation column where the yearly average temperature will be added.

How can I get this done by using `dplyr` or `data.table` for `excel` data? Any easier way to make this data aggregation operation on attached data on the fly [time series data](http://jmp.sh/v/dXIe4QmEGdqrmmAY4eoO)? Any thought?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @hpesoj626 I looked into `dplyr::summarize` but the number of days will be varied slightly every year, and I didn't get the clean output. Any idea?

Comment: @hpesoj626 why geo-coordinate pair x, y get rounded? I want to preserve their original value, while I want to get an integer value for the rest. How can I do this? Any possible update?

Comment: This is just how `tidyverse` displays data. If you save the file into csv by `write_csv(demo_data, "demo.csv"), you will see that `demo.csv` has the unrounded values.

Comment: @datageek just added that in my post, you can check if its still needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried that:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("YOUR_XLSX_FILE")

df %>% 
  gather(date, temp, -x, -y) %>% 
  separate(date, c("year", "month", "day")) %>% 
  separate(year, c("trash", "year"), sep = "X") %>% 
  select(-trash) %>% 
  group_by(year, x, y) %>% 
  summarise(avg_temp=mean(temp)) %>% 
  spread(year, avg_temp)
```

output is:

```
# A tibble: 19 x 17
# Groups: x [11]
       x     y `1980` `1981` `1982` `1983` `1984` `1985` `1986` `1987` `1988` `1989` `1990` `1991`
 * <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  8.88  54.4   7.79   8.02   8.76   9.20   8.32   7.51   7.88   7.43   9.20   9.63   9.76   8.55
 2  8.88  54.9   7.54   7.61   8.41   8.84   8.15   7.15   7.53   7.15   8.97   9.51   9.55   8.42
 3  9.12  54.4   7.65   7.86   8.62   9.05   8.17   7.34   7.70   7.28   9.01   9.46   9.60   8.37
 4  9.12  54.6   7.44   7.59   8.38   8.81   8.02   7.11   7.50   7.13   8.88   9.36   9.47   8.31
 5  9.12  54.9   7.33   7.36   8.25   8.67   8.02   7.05   7.49   7.10   8.91   9.48   9.55   8.41
 6  9.38  54.4   7.69   7.91   8.61   9.02   8.15   7.31   7.69   7.24   8.98   9.49   9.64   8.35
 7  9.38  54.6   7.45   7.62   8.46   8.85   8.05   7.16   7.59   7.18   8.92   9.48   9.61   8.41
 8  9.38  54.9   7.24   7.29   8.21   8.62   7.95   7.04   7.56   7.15   8.94   9.57   9.66   8.53
 9  9.62  54.4   7.65   7.90   8.60   9.01   8.14   7.24   7.64   7.16   8.93   9.52   9.65   8.33
10  9.62  54.6   7.39   7.60   8.45   8.82   8.01   7.10   7.56   7.12   8.86   9.46   9.55   8.34
11  9.62  54.9   7.28   7.38   8.28   8.69   7.98   7.07   7.61   7.18   8.96   9.60   9.68   8.54
12  9.88  54.4   7.70   8.00   8.69   9.14   8.23   7.36   7.76   7.23   9.03   9.63   9.73   8.41
13  9.88  54.6   7.40   7.65   8.46   8.87   8.05   7.11   7.58   7.12   8.87   9.47   9.50   8.30
14 10.1   54.4   7.76   8.12   8.78   9.21   8.30   7.49   7.90   7.34   9.08   9.69   9.79   8.52
15 10.4   54.4   7.66   8.09   8.70   9.17   8.23   7.41   7.87   7.29   9.03   9.70   9.82   8.60
16 11.1   54.9   7.61   8.14   8.74   9.14   8.33   7.32   7.92   7.22   9.17   9.93  10.1    8.86
17 11.4   54.9   7.59   8.17   8.74   9.14   8.32   7.29   7.92   7.20   9.17   9.95  10.1    8.87
18 11.9   54.9   7.54   8.15   8.71   9.10   8.28   7.19   7.85   7.15   9.10   9.92  10.1    8.84
19 12.1   54.9   7.52   8.12   8.69   9.08   8.27   7.12   7.80   7.11   9.05   9.91  10.0    8.82
# ... with 3 more variables: `1992` <dbl>, `1993` <dbl>, `1994` <dbl>
```

to show you that the geocoordinates are not changed in a `tibble` (it's just rounded), add `as.data.frame()` at the end of the pipe and look at your data: an example:

```
df %>% 
  gather(date, temp, -x, -y) %>% 
  separate(date, c("year", "month", "day")) %>% 
  separate(year, c("trash", "year"), sep = "X") %>% 
  select(-trash) %>% 
  group_by(year, x, y) %>% 
  summarise(avg_temp=mean(temp)) %>% 
  spread(year, avg_temp) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% # add this
  head()
```

output is:

```
#       x      y     1980     1981     1982     1983     1984     1985     1986     1987     1988
# 1 8.875 54.375 7.792978 8.021342 8.762274 9.203424 8.317131 7.505370 7.879068 7.427260 9.197431
# 2 8.875 54.875 7.536229 7.607507 8.414877 8.841260 8.154945 7.151890 7.532164 7.147945 8.969781
# 3 9.125 54.375 7.651393 7.862466 8.620904 9.052630 8.169262 7.337589 7.701205 7.282657 9.014590
# 4 9.125 54.625 7.435983 7.590548 8.381753 8.808904 8.019399 7.109096 7.499589 7.127370 8.875656
# 5 9.125 54.875 7.332978 7.363370 8.247205 8.669370 8.024645 7.045425 7.487424 7.098849 8.911776
# 6 9.375 54.375 7.693907 7.914630 8.612438 9.022055 8.150164 7.305068 7.688164 7.242274 8.984207
#       1989     1990     1991     1992     1993     1994
# 1 9.625781 9.760931 8.550356 9.678907 8.208109 9.390904
# 2 9.513863 9.552767 8.420109 9.425328 8.010082 9.134466
# 3 9.462959 9.602876 8.374575 9.465164 8.052794 9.207041
# 4 9.358986 9.473178 8.305863 9.353743 7.935507 9.050109
# 5 9.478192 9.545781 8.412329 9.403005 7.998877 9.074740
# 6 9.493205 9.635561 8.352740 9.385819 8.017260 9.184959
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on the data that you provided.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
demo_data %>%
  gather(date, temp, -x, -y) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(str_remove(date, "X"))) %>%
  mutate(year = year(date)) %>%
  group_by(x, y, year) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(temp), mean, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  spread(year, temp)

# # A tibble: 19 x 17
# # Groups:   x, y [19]
#        x     y `1980` `1981` `1982` `1983` `1984` `1985` `1986` `1987` `1988`
#    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1  8.88  54.4   7.79   8.02   8.76   9.20   8.32   7.51   7.88   7.43   9.20
#  2  8.88  54.9   7.54   7.61   8.41   8.84   8.15   7.15   7.53   7.15   8.97
#  3  9.12  54.4   7.65   7.86   8.62   9.05   8.17   7.34   7.70   7.28   9.01
#  4  9.12  54.6   7.44   7.59   8.38   8.81   8.02   7.11   7.50   7.13   8.88
#  5  9.12  54.9   7.33   7.36   8.25   8.67   8.02   7.05   7.49   7.10   8.91
#  6  9.38  54.4   7.69   7.91   8.61   9.02   8.15   7.31   7.69   7.24   8.98
#  7  9.38  54.6   7.45   7.62   8.46   8.85   8.05   7.16   7.59   7.18   8.92
#  8  9.38  54.9   7.24   7.29   8.21   8.62   7.95   7.04   7.56   7.15   8.94
#  9  9.62  54.4   7.65   7.90   8.60   9.01   8.14   7.24   7.64   7.16   8.93
# 10  9.62  54.6   7.39   7.60   8.45   8.82   8.01   7.10   7.56   7.12   8.86
# 11  9.62  54.9   7.28   7.38   8.28   8.69   7.98   7.07   7.61   7.18   8.96
# 12  9.88  54.4   7.70   8.00   8.69   9.14   8.23   7.36   7.76   7.23   9.03
# 13  9.88  54.6   7.40   7.65   8.46   8.87   8.05   7.11   7.58   7.12   8.87
# 14 10.1   54.4   7.76   8.12   8.78   9.21   8.30   7.49   7.90   7.34   9.08
# 15 10.4   54.4   7.66   8.09   8.70   9.17   8.23   7.41   7.87   7.29   9.03
# 16 11.1   54.9   7.61   8.14   8.74   9.14   8.33   7.32   7.92   7.22   9.17
# 17 11.4   54.9   7.59   8.17   8.74   9.14   8.32   7.29   7.92   7.20   9.17
# 18 11.9   54.9   7.54   8.15   8.71   9.10   8.28   7.19   7.85   7.15   9.10
# 19 12.1   54.9   7.52   8.12   8.69   9.08   8.27   7.12   7.80   7.11   9.05
# # ... with 6 more variables: `1989` <dbl>, `1990` <dbl>, `1991` <dbl>,
# #   `1992` <dbl>, `1993` <dbl>, `1994` <dbl>
```